# Settings for Pgpool-2 and 2 read replicas, goal is to split connections evenly between two replicas

Tags: pgpool

My setup:
pgpool-2 V4.0.2
OS Ubuntu
2 aws rds read replicas (master db not included in the setup)
pgpool mode: master_slave mode + sub-mode streaming replication

Purpose of using pgpool (have not achieved)
Evenly split incoming db connections between two replicas, e.g. when there are 20 db connections come to pgpool, pgpool will open 10 connections to replica 1 and open 10 connections to replica 2.

Things that my current setup can do 
Load balancing queries, cache connections, watch-dog fail over.

Answer (score 0):

I got reply from official Pgpool-2 developer. Pgpool-2 does not split connections, it handles load balancing for query only, not for connections.